# Is it normal that the ping on DayZ always goes up and down?

Tags: dayz-2012

Playing DayZ with a friend, we noticed that it is possible for us to be killed while only hearing a single shot from an automatic weapon, and that we might shoot at an attacker without any effect. Is it possible that our problem is our latency? I live in Belgium, he lives in Bulgaria, and the server is in Germany. Our latency can fluctuate between 20 and 90 milliseconds. Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

Fluctuations of 50-100 milliseconds of latency are perfectly normal for online gaming. Over the space of a protracted World of Warcraft gaming session I have seen my latency go from between 20 and 100 milliseconds regularly. Latency can change based on network load between you and the server as well as factors in your setup, such as local wifi interference or other people on your connection or programs on your computer using bandwidth. Fluctuations like this can have a small amount of effect on your gameplay, especially in first-person shooter games, where fast reaction times are very important.